# The documentation library for tcolorbox overrides hypersetup

Tags: hyperref, tcolorbox

I'm typesetting a document where I'd like to add margin notes in colored boxes and I'd also like to be able to control the colors for hyperlinks. I apparently can't have both with my current setup and I haven't figured out a way to fix it yet, though I've narrowed down the cause.

The boxed margin notes are produced using the `tcolorbox` package, specifically `\tcbdocmarginnote`, which requires me to load the `documentation` library in the preamble. However, loading this library also loads settings for hyperref that override anything I put in via `hypersetup`.

Side by side comparison of what I get by commenting out (left) and leaving in the line `\tcbuselibrary{documentation}`:
[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[marginparwidth=4.5cm, inner=2cm, outer=5cm, marginparsep=4mm, bottom=3cm, top=2cm]{geometry}%
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{HintColor}{RGB}{59, 189, 236}

\usepackage{marginnote} % Make room for margin notes
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
%% Commenting out this line uses the hypersetup colors. Leaving it in yields an option clash with the hyperref package.
% \tcbuselibrary{documentation}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}

\newcommand{\MarBox}[3][]{
    \tcbdocmarginnote[
   floatplacement=htb,
   box align=center,
   title=#3,
   width=4.2cm,
   left=1.5mm,
   right=1.5mm,
   top=1.5mm,
   bottom=1.5mm,
   fontupper=\small,
   fonttitle=\bfseries\color{White},
   colframe=#2!70,
   colback=#2!10]
#1
}
\newcommand{\Hint}[1][]{
\MarBox[#1]{HintColor}{Hint}
}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{%
breaklinks,
colorlinks=true,
citecolor=yellow,
linkcolor=green,
anchorcolor=blue,
urlcolor=red,
filecolor=magenta,
pdfauthor={AUTHOR},
pdftitle={TITLE}}

\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}
\begin{document}
\title{Clash}
\author{}
\date{}
\maketitle
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}
This URL link and the hyperlink in the table of contents should be different colors: \href{https://stackexchange.com/}{Stack Exchange}.
\tableofcontents

\section{This is the wrong color}
I can either get this box, or the right color on the hyperlinks, but not both. \Hint{I can't print this without also overriding the hypersetup colors.}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tcolorbox sets colors at begin document, so you must delay some of the settings:

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks}
\AtBeginDocument{
\hypersetup{%
citecolor=yellow,
linkcolor=green,
anchorcolor=blue,
urlcolor=red,
filecolor=magenta,
pdfauthor={AUTHOR},
pdftitle={TITLE}}}
```

Comment: Still get an option clash. It seems to be using different defaults, boxing the links with colors other than the ones I defined. ETA: I forgot the first hypersetup. This works great. Thank you!